# Discrete mathematics bit strings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So my question is that let's say I have a bit string of length four. If it is illegal to have 3 1's in a row and 3 0's in a row then how many bit string of this type exists

I was thinking that in total combination of bit strings of length four there is $2^4$, but in this case there is 2+2 illegal combinations so the total is

$2^4-4$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Are $0000$ and $1111$ allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There are $6$ illegal strings. Just write them out. Unless 'three in a row' means *exactly* three in a row ... but that's not how I would interpret that question ...

Comment: how is there 6?

Comment: 0000,0001,1000,0111,1110,1111

Comment: ahhh I forgot the four of the same

Comment: so it should be $2^4-6$?

Comment: @JoeHansen Exactly.  But, like I said, maybe it means *exactly* three in a row .. but that's not how I read that question ... so yes, I think you need to rule out 0000 and 1111 as well

Comment: Yea I think you're right because there's also 3 in a row when there's four in a row :)

Comment: @JoeHansen Yes, that's what I would say as well. To be safe, you could always write down the two different interpretations and corresponding answers.